# complex analysis question concerning residues

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the residue at $z = 0$ of $z\cos(\frac{1}{z})$. Its not really the problem I am having trouble with. It is the "find the residue at $z = 0$" part. What does that mean, and how do I use this information on the given problem? What if it said at $z = 4$? I am not sure what it means.

However I do know that $z\cos(\frac{1}{z}) = z - \frac{1}{z2!} + \frac{1}{z^34!} - ... $

Answer (score 4):

The *residue* of a function at $z=a$ is defined to be the coefficient by $(z-a)^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion for the function about $z=a$.

In this case, you want to find the coefficient by $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion of $z\cos(\frac{1}{z})$. But, we know that
$$
\cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2n}=1-\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{1}{24z^4}+\cdots,
$$
so that
$$
z\cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2n-1},
$$
so that the coefficient by $z^{-1}$ is from the $n=1$ term, which gives $-\frac{1}{2}$. So, the residue is $-\frac{1}{2}$.

As for how you use this information in the given problem... well, since you haven't given us the problem, it is hard to say!

Comment: Is $z_0=0$ an example of an essential singularity? (sorry for reviving the dead haha)